# Jenkins Active Choices Parameter groovy script fails to read filesystem

Tags: jenkins, groovy, plugins

The following groovy script works in the jenkins script console on the controller.  However, it fails if I change the path to `/path/to/workspace/prod_file.json` and run the script on an agent node.

`prod_file.json` is pulled from github, otherwise they're the same. `prod_file.json` gets its trailing newline stripped, but even when that char is restored, the script fails.  The permissions are the least restrictive (777).  I even tried reading the file in python, and dumping it back to the fs as a new json file.  I tried reading the file from `/tmp`, `$HOME`, `$WORKSPACE`, `$WORKSPACE/other_project`, etc.

I also tried the dot delimited path in `add`, e.g., `add(it.jenkins_name)`

The plugin provides *no feedback*, so I'm not sure where else to turn.

Is this a configuration issue, i.e., permissions, a file format issue, a bug in the plugin?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def list = []
File textfile = new File('/tmp/test.json') 
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsedJson = slurper.parse(textfile)
parsedJson.each{ list.add(it['jenkins_name']) }
return list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Choices groovy script always runs on the controller node. Simple test:

```
def host = 'hostname'.execute().text
return [host]
```